# Combining and/or statements crashing database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql select. It gets the list of the users qualified on the event and it also gets some results from the users table.

```
SELECT event.*,
       users.first_name,
       users.last_name,
       users.login,
       users.email,
       users.f_phone as userphone,
       users.f_phone_code 
 FROM  event,
       users 
 WHERE (users.id=event.h_user and f_code LIKE %NEW%) 
       OR event.h_user = -1
 ORDER BY event.`h_id` DESC
```

Everything worked perfectly, until I tried to get more results by adding the records with `h_user = -1`. There is not a lot of them, but I guess my query isn't good enough while the database of users is really big. The added `OR` statement is crashing database while getting results. I tried to add the brackets in WHERE statement but they arent helping.

Would you mind to help me on this please?

Comment: You could split the conditions into two SELECTs and do a UNION. That should be a bit faster than OR.

Comment: I was sure that my query wasnt correct or something. Thank you a lot I will try doing this

Answer (score 2):

It happens because your implicit join conditions become messed up when u add `or` in the `where` clause, thus the query doesn't work as you expect it to. Try using explicit `join` instead (u can make the query work both ways, but explicit notation is just more readable) and leave all the filtering in the `where` clause:

```
from  event
join users on users.id = event.h_user
where f_code like '%NEW%' or event.h_user = -1
```

Which would look like this using the implicit notation (*don't use it, it is deprecated*):

```
from  event, users 
where ( users.id = event.h_user ) and
      ( f_code like '%NEW%' or event.h_user = -1 )
```

Comment: I will try this one. Thank you a lot

Comment: Well, if someone has h_user = -1 in event table, he still doesnt appear on my list. What happens? SQL is so confusing :D

Comment: @divHelper11 I guess u need `left join` instead of `inner join`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with joins and a UNION:

```
SELECT event.*,
       users.first_name,
       users.last_name,
       users.login,
       users.email,
       users.f_phone as userphone,
       users.f_phone_code 
 FROM  event
 INNER JOIN users ON users.id=event.h_user
 WHERE f_code LIKE %NEW%
 UNION
 SELECT event.*,
       users.first_name,
       users.last_name,
       users.login,
       users.email,
       users.f_phone as userphone,
       users.f_phone_code 
 FROM  event
 INNER JOIN users ON users.id=event.h_user
 WHERE event.h_user = -1
 ORDER BY event.`h_id` DESC
```

Comment: `Syntax error or access violation` I do not have any access problems. Is here any mistake that I cannot see? (I already put %NEW% into brackets)